# How to evaluate an expression from an argument of a function multiple times in r?

Tags: r

Maybe the title of the question is not the best, but the problem is simple to explain: I have a function where one of its arguments is an expression (i.e. one or more lines of code to be evaluated).

```
myFUN <- function(x) eval(quote(x))

myFUN(x = {
  print(1 + 3)
  print(mean(mtcars$mpg))
})

[1] 4
[1] 20.09062
```

The problem appears when I try to place that evaluation inside a loop. What I expect is that it is evaluated as many times as there are steps in the loop, but it only seems to happen once.

```
myFUN <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:5){
    eval(quote(x))
  }
}

myFUN(x = {
  print(1 + 3)
  print(mean(mtcars$mpg))
})

[1] 4
[1] 20.09062
```

In other words, what I would expect to get in the second case is the following:

```
myFUN(x = {
  print(1 + 3)
  print(mean(mtcars$mpg))
})

[1] 4
[1] 20.09062
[1] 4
[1] 20.09062
[1] 4
[1] 20.09062
[1] 4
[1] 20.09062
[1] 4
[1] 20.09062
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `substitute` instead

```
myFUN <- function(x) {
  for(i in 1:5) {
    eval(substitute(x))
  }
}

myFUN(x = {
  print(1 + 3)
  print(mean(mtcars$mpg))
})

# [1] 4
# [1] 20.091
# [1] 4
# [1] 20.091
# [1] 4
# [1] 20.091
# [1] 4
# [1] 20.091
# [1] 4
# [1] 20.091
```